# INSERT don't returning multiple generated ids

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am currently trying to implement an insert (see https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-returning/). The difference is that I don't use values ​​directly, but the set with record.

In the log I see that 2 inserts are executed, but in the Records Result there is always only 1 result. Test is with H2.

```
FooRecord foo1;
FooRecord foo2;

   final Result<?> result =
            create.insertInto( FOO)
                  .set( foo1 )
                  .set( foo2 )
                  .returningResult( FOO.ID )
                  .fetch();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the example of the [`INSERT .. SET` documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-set/), which lists a call to `newRecord()`. You have to place a marker between your records to clearly distinguish between them:

```java
final Result<?> result =
create.insertInto( FOO)
      .set( foo1 )
      .newRecord() // This call is necessary
      .set( foo2 )
      .returningResult( FOO.ID )
      .fetch();
```

Otherwise, the consecutive `set()` calls just override one another.